# Unable to echo value of an element in Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am using geoplugin to know country of a user. On the website they write following code:

```
echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
```

and the result is:

```
array (
'geoplugin_request' => '59.179.68.40',
'geoplugin_status' => 206,
'geoplugin_credit' => 'Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from http://www.maxmind.com.',
'geoplugin_city' => '',
'geoplugin_region' => '',
'geoplugin_areaCode' => '0',
'geoplugin_dmaCode' => '0',
'geoplugin_countryCode' => 'IN',
'geoplugin_countryName' => 'India',
'geoplugin_continentCode' => 'AS',
'geoplugin_latitude' => '20',
'geoplugin_longitude' => '77',
'geoplugin_regionCode' => '',
'geoplugin_regionName' => NULL,
'geoplugin_currencyCode' => 'INR',
'geoplugin_currencySymbol' => '₨',
'geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8' => '₨',
'geoplugin_currencyConverter' => '63.4999',
 )
```

Now, I tried to store it in an array like this:

```
$locArray = var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
```

and echo the location like:

```
echo $locArray[8];
```

Instead of echoing the 9th element, the code echos complete array like this:

```
array ( 'geoplugin_request' => '59.179.68.40', 'geoplugin_status' => 206, 'geoplugin_credit' => 'Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from http://www.maxmind.com.', 'geoplugin_city' => '', 'geoplugin_region' => '', 'geoplugin_areaCode' => '0', 'geoplugin_dmaCode' => '0', 'geoplugin_countryCode' => 'IN', 'geoplugin_countryName' => 'India', 'geoplugin_continentCode' => 'AS', 'geoplugin_latitude' => '20', 'geoplugin_longitude' => '77', 'geoplugin_regionCode' => '', 'geoplugin_regionName' => NULL, 'geoplugin_currencyCode' => 'INR', 'geoplugin_currencySymbol' => '₨', 'geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8' => 'â‚¨', 'geoplugin_currencyConverter' => '63.4999', )
```

How can I extract just country name from it?

Comment: Well, it seems like the 9th element in `$locArray` is itself an array. You already seem to know how to access arrays. What's the problem?

Comment: How can I extract just the country name then?

Comment: Assume you have `$data = array('geoplugin_countryName' => 'foo');`, what would you do?

Comment: @FelixKling I am editing the question to be more clear.

Comment: You could just answer my question. Do you not know how to access `geoplugin_countryName` in my example?

Comment: I know but it echo complete array when I do that. I have tried it.

Comment: So you know how to access `geoplugin_countryName` in my example and you know that `$locArray[8]` is an array. Consequently you should know that you can access the data you want with `$locArray[8]['geoplugin_countryName']`. Maybe you did not know that arrays can contain other arrays?

Comment: Or maybe not since you now changed the question. If the array is really like you said it is, then `echo $locArray[8];` won't print anything since it doesn't have an index `8`. What are you reporting is inconsistent. I suggest you spend some more time to figure what data you *really* have.

Comment: @SandipPatel did you tried my code?

Comment: Again, what you are reporting is impossible. See: http://codepad.org/9HXDeoyy. No output.

Comment: But I see what the problem is. You are still using `var_export`. Have a look at what `var_export` does: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: Why don't you just use their [provided class](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php#php_class) to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
//  then just access the country index. 
echo $arr['geoplugin_countryCode'];
```

Edit:

You are trying `echo $locArray[8];` but there is not index `8` because it is associative array (an array whose indexes are Strings).

Answer (score 0):

This return an array like

```
array (
  'geoplugin_request' => '192.168.4.188',
  'geoplugin_status' => 404,
  'geoplugin_credit' => 'Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from http://www.maxmind.com.',
  'geoplugin_city' => '',
  'geoplugin_region' => '',
  'geoplugin_areaCode' => '',
  'geoplugin_dmaCode' => '',
  'geoplugin_countryCode' => '',
  'geoplugin_countryName' => '',
  'geoplugin_continentCode' => '',
  'geoplugin_latitude' => '0',
  'geoplugin_longitude' => '0',
  'geoplugin_regionCode' => '',
  'geoplugin_regionName' => NULL,
  'geoplugin_currencyCode' => NULL,
  'geoplugin_currencySymbol' => NULL,
  'geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8' => '',
  'geoplugin_currencyConverter' => '0',
)
```

and then you can use like

```
echo $locArray['geoplugin_request'];
```